# Reference numbers appear in Overleaf but don't appear in journal pdf proof when I upload the related .TeX documents

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, natbib

I prepared a paper in Overleaf. There is not any problem in References' numbers in the PDF document in Overleaf or TexStudio in my local computer. However,  when I uploaded the TeX documents to Journal, the reference numbers seem as "question mark" ("?") after the journal's pdf proof has been created. I couldn't solve the problem. When I look at the log file there are things such as the errors related to citation like:

Package natbib Warning: Citation 'xxx' on page 7 undefined on input line 212.

Package natbib Warning: Citation 'yyy' on page 10 undefined on input line 286.

In summary, there weren'T any problem in Overleaf, but the Journal's online pdf proof doesn't include the references with their numbers such as (1) (2) instead they appear as question marks ("????").

I am waiting your help. Thank you. I am also adding the all my .bib file:

```
@article{granet1998designing,
  title={Designing axially symmetric Cassegrain or Gregorian dual-reflector antennas from combinations of prescribed geometric parameters},
  author={Granet, Christophe},
  journal={IEEE Antennas and Propagation Magazine},
  volume={40},
  number={2},
  pages={76--82},
  year={1998},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{rajagopalan2013experimental,
  title={Experimental demonstration of reflectarrays acting as conic section subreflectors in a dual reflector system},
  author={Rajagopalan, Harish and Xu, Shenheng and Rahmat-Samii, Yahya},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Antennas and propagation},
  volume={61},
  number={11},
  pages={5475--5484},
  year={2013},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{chou2013analytic,
  title={Analytic transient analysis of radiation from hyperboloid reflector antennas via surface curvature continuation of ellipsoidal surfaces},
  author={Chou, H-T and Tuan, S-C},
  journal={Electronics Letters},
  volume={49},
  number={6},
  pages={381--382},
  year={2013},
  publisher={IET}
}

@article{haeger1990comparisons,
  title={Comparisons between a shaped and nonshaped small Cassegrain antenna},
  author={Haeger, Thomas A and Lee, JJ},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation},
  volume={38},
  number={12},
  pages={1920--1924},
  year={1990},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{agrawal1979design,
  title={Design of a dichroic Cassegrain subreflector},
  author={Agrawal, V and Imbriale, W},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation},
  volume={27},
  number={4},
  pages={466--473},
  year={1979},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{xiao2010new,
  title={New type optical Cassegrain antenna with lenses telescope system},
  author={Xiao, Liuping and Yang, Huajun and Liu, Xiaojing and Xu, Quan and Xiong, Xinqiang},
  journal={Optik-International Journal for Light and Electron Optics},
  volume={121},
  number={6},
  pages={521--525},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{ma2014optimum,
  title={An optimum structure design for Cassegrain optical system},
  author={Ma, Xiaojun and Yang, Huajun and Wang, Bing and Jiang, Ping and Yu, Mingyin and Huang, Yuchun and Ke, Shasha},
  journal={Optik-International Journal for Light and Electron Optics},
  volume={125},
  number={3},
  pages={1423--1426},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{chen2012theoretical,
  title={Theoretical analysis and test for off-axis Cassegrain optical antenna},
  author={Chen, Zihao and Yang, Huajun and Wang, Xinyang and Wang, Jing and Huang, Xiaoping},
  journal={Optik-International Journal for Light and Electron Optics},
  volume={123},
  number={3},
  pages={268--271},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{ding1982flat,
  title={A flat-field reflecting focal reducer},
  author={Ding-Qiang, Su and Lan-Juan, Wang},
  journal={Optica Acta: International Journal of Optics},
  volume={29},
  number={4},
  pages={391--394},
  year={1982},
  publisher={Taylor \& Francis}
}

@article{su1982configuration,
  title={A configuration of the optical system for a 5 m telescope.},
  author={Su, D-Q and Shao, L-Z and Liang, Ming},
  journal={Optica Acta},
  volume={29},
  pages={1237--1242},
  year={1982}
}

@book{silver1984microwave,
  title={Microwave antenna theory and design},
  author={Silver, Samuel},
  year={1984},
  publisher={Iet}
}

@article{keller1962geometrical,
  title={Geometrical theory of diffraction},
  author={Keller, Joseph B},
  journal={JOSA},
  volume={52},
  number={2},
  pages={116--130},
  year={1962},
  publisher={Optical Society of America}
}

@article{lewis1969uniform,
  title={Uniform asymptotic theory of edge diffraction},
  author={Lewis, Robert M and Boersma, Johannes},
  journal={Journal of Mathematical physics},
  volume={10},
  number={12},
  pages={2291--2305},
  year={1969},
  publisher={AIP}
}

@article{kouyoumjian1974uniform,
  title={A uniform geometrical theory of diffraction for an edge in a perfectly conducting surface},
  author={Kouyoumjian, Robert G and Pathak, Prabhakar H},
  journal={Proceedings of the IEEE},
  volume={62},
  number={11},
  pages={1448--1461},
  year={1974},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@book{ufimtsev2009theory,
  title={Theory of edge diffraction in electromagnetics},
  author={Ufimtsev, Pyotr},
  year={2009},
  publisher={The Institution of Engineering and Technology}
}

@article{macdonald1913x,
  title={X. The effect produced by an obstacle on a train of electric waves},
  author={Macdonald, Hector Munro},
  journal={Philosophical Transactions of the Royal Society of London. Series A, Containing Papers of a Mathematical or Physical Character},
  volume={212},
  number={484-496},
  pages={299--337},
  year={1913},
  publisher={The Royal Society London}
}

@article{umul2004modified,
  title={Modified theory of physical optics},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Z},
  journal={Optics Express},
  volume={12},
  number={20},
  pages={4959--4972},
  year={2004},
  publisher={Optical Society of America}
}

@article{umul2006modified,
  title={Modified theory of physical optics solution of impedance half plane problem},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Z},
  journal={IEEE Transactions on Antennas and Propagation},
  volume={54},
  number={7},
  pages={2048--2053},
  year={2006},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{umul2005diffraction,
  title={Diffraction by a black half plane: modified theory of physical optics approach},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Z},
  journal={Optics Express},
  volume={13},
  number={19},
  pages={7276--7287},
  year={2005},
  publisher={Optical Society of America}
}

@article{umul2011physical,
  title={Physical optics scattering of waves by a half-plane with different face impedances},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Ziya},
  journal={IEEE Antennas and Wireless Propagation Letters},
  volume={10},
  pages={21--24},
  year={2011},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@article{umul2014physical,
  title={The physical optics integral on the scatterer's unlit surface},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Z},
  journal={Optik},
  volume={125},
  number={18},
  pages={5085--5092},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}

@article{safak1989radiation,
  title={Radiation pattern of an offset hyperbolic reflector},
  author={Safak, Mehmet},
  journal={IEEE transactions on antennas and propagation},
  volume={37},
  number={2},
  pages={251--253},
  year={1989},
  publisher={IEEE}
}

@inproceedings{elkamchouchi1998analysis,
  title={Analysis of parabolic and hyperbolic cylindrical reflector antennas using the method of moments},
  author={Elkamchouchi, YH and Elkamchouchi, HM and El-Khamy, SE},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the Fifteenth National Radio Science Conference. NRSC'98 (Cat. No. 98EX109)},
  pages={B4--1},
  year={1998},
  organization={IEEE}
}

@article{umul2008scattering,
  title={Scattering of a line source by a cylindrical parabolic impedance surface},
  author={Umul, Yusuf Z},
  journal={JOSA A},
  volume={25},
  number={7},
  pages={1652--1659},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Optical Society of America}
}

@book{collin1985antennas,
  title={Antennas and radiowave propagation},
  author={Collin, Robert E},
  year={1985},
  publisher={McGraw-Hill}
}
```

Comment: It will depend on what the journal say you need to do with bib part of submission if your format is not their format or they do not multi-process the way you do there will be a difference 1)read the guide for authors with that in mind

Comment: did you upload the generated bbl file? the journal will need that if it doesn't run bibtex